TypeORM stuck on RDS reader node after failover
I am having some strange issues with TypeORM when performing failover in RDS. I am currently using RDS Aurora MySQL, and when I perform a failover, I get the following message when attempting to insert a record:
The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

I have confirmed that the application is connected to the cluster writer endpoint (not direct node endpoint). In theory, when we do failover, the application should try to establish the connection back to the writer endpoint due to the the CNAME swap performed by RDS.
Is there a caching of the database host/IP within TypeORM that is preventing failvovers to always point to writer endpoint? Wondering if anyone has seen this issue before.
PS: I performed a failover again (2nd time) and query inserts without issue, which confirms me that TypeORM did not detect the CNAME change.
Thanks!

What is your question? You appear to have resolved it, and it was not a code problem.

Well, I should not have to perform a second failover to get the application working again. I want to be able to failover with minimal downtime. This mean that it I failover the first time, I errors when inserting, and if I basically revert th e failover by switching back, the error goes away. This is because TypeORM seems to be caching the original connection.
